given an arbitrary primitive character mod q, can you induce a imprimitive character based on it?
We know that given any imprimitive character $\chi$ we can always define a smaller primitive character that's identical to $\chi$ with mod $q$ where $q$ is the conductor of $\chi$. I wonder if we could do the reverse process where given any primitive character can you induce a larger imprimitive character that has the conductor of the moduli of the primitive character and is identical to it. Thanks!

First of all, an imprimitive character $\chi$ modulo $q$ and the primitive character $\chi^*$ modulo $q^*$ (say) that induces it are not identical. Rather, their values agree on all integers that are relatively prime to $q$. But $\chi^*$ can take nonzero values on integers that are relatively prime to $q^*$ but not to $q$, while $\chi$ cannot.
As for the main question: yes, very easily in fact. Let $\chi^*$ be any primitive character mod $q^*$, let $m$ be any positive integer, and let $\chi_0$ be the principal character mod $m$. Then $\chi_0\chi^*$ (the pointwise product of the two functions) is a character mod lcm$[m,q^*]$, and will be imprimitive if $m\nmid q^*$.
